# Why is OnCreate() called twice but savedInstance remains null

Tags: android, oncreate, savestate

I have `ListActivty onCreate()` where  a list adapter is set with a cursor object holding all data within a database.

I have a search method in this ListActivity that calls a method in another database activity to retrieve a Cursor from a search, and returns the cursor to my ListActivity.

However after this method is called the `ListActivty onCreate()` is called again, where the the original list adapter with all data is called again, therefore I can never see the search results when i try to set the adapter with search cursor.

I have tried setting a boolean flag fro when savedInstance != null to set the correct search adapter but the savedInstance ALWAYS remains null......

So my question what is actually happening to the activity when the `onCreate()` is called twice?

EDIT: Added code
onCreate() I set the list apdter

```
public class ViewListOfTests  extends ListActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{.....

    this.setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

                     // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
                     searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
                        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
                        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
                        searchView.setOnCloseListener( this);

                    SearchManager searchManager =
                           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                    //SearchView searchView =(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
                    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    //(SearchView) this.findViewById(id) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();


            /*call the aysnch inner class to load cursor form Db and set teh customer adter to this list view
            *off the main UI thread, cast to type (getCursor)
            *Asynch class does not have a constructor in this case
            **/

                    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                        //getCursorAysnch = (getCursor) new getCursor().execute();
                        searchPerformed=true;
                    }
            //getCursorAysnch = (getCursor) new getCursor().execute();
                    try{
                    noOftimesOnCreateCalled = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
                    searchPerformed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("VIEWLISTTESTS", "noOFTOMESONCREATECALLED NOT CALLED");
                    }



                    if (noOftimesOnCreateCalled>0){
                        this.setListAdapter(searchAdapter);
                        Log.d("VIEWLISTOFDIVES", "IN ONCTREATE SERACHPERFOMED + TRUE");
                    }else if(noOftimesOnCreateCalled==0){
                        getCursorAysnch = (getCursor) new getCursor().execute();
                        Log.d("VIEWLISTOFDIVES", "IN ONCTREATE SERACHPERFOMED + FALSE");
                        noOftimesOnCreateCalled++;
                    }
```

I get the search query fem a searchView widget and call the following methow with the query, after this method the oCreate() is  be called again...

```
@Override

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //handleIntent(intent);
    Log.d("LIST ACTIVITY SEARCH", "onQueryTextCahanged called: "+ newText);
    data = new database(this);
    Cursor c = data.getWordMatches(newText, null);

    Log.d("LISTACTIVITY", "CURSOR QUERY ROWS/COLS = "+ c.getCount()+" "+c.getColumnCount());

    //now set bind cursor data to list view using custim ItemAdpter class
    //ItemAdapter newAdapter = new ItemAdapter(ViewListOfTests.this, c);
    //newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //ViewListOfTests.this.setListAdapter(newAdapter);
    searchAdapter= new ItemAdapter(this, c);
    //this.setListAdapter(searchAdapter);
    searchPerformed=true;
    return false;
}
```

Although savediNstanceState always remains nul I try to saved variables here:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
      // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
      // killed and restarted ie when we go ot ItemAdter to craete a new adpter with serach 

      //savedInstanceState.putBoolean(key, false)
      savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
      savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
      savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
      // etc.
    }


    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
      // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
      searchPerformed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
      double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
       noOftimesOnCreateCalled = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
      String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
    }
```

Comment: do you have any code you can post?

Comment: Please post your code as well necessary logcat error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was I had some code to configure the searchable widget with a ACTION_SERACH intent when user submitted query :

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // call handleIntent from here to handle the query from serah widget

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        handleIntent(intent);

    }//end onNewIntent


// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

I had forgotten to delete this code as wasn't aiming to configure search view with a ACTION_SEARCH intent, but I believe this intent was called and then calling the onCreate() again.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `onCreate()`'s `savedInstanceState` to be non-null, you have to provide Android with the saved state when Android forces the Activity to exit.

To do this, you must override the [void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method and fill in the passed-in `savedInstanceState` Bundle with whatever state you want.